# fadeOut() and fadeIn() not working in IE 11 for Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

**This line just seems to not read in IE. But it works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.** I'm not sure how this looks in other IEs, but the  IE in question is **IE 11.** The problem is there is no fade transition of any kind displaying in IE, but I'm calling a `fadeIn()` and a `fadeOut()` and it reads everywhere else! In IE it just clunkily hides and then shows next slide. Any thoughts as to why..

```
$('.img-wrap .slideZ:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
```

Full code.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="paginateyo">
            <div class="prevbox">
            <img src="images/prev_arrow.jpg" id="prv" alt="Previous"/>
            <span class="prvp">previous</span>
            </div>
            /
            <div class="nextbox">
            <span class="nxtp">next</span>
            <img src="images/next_arrow.jpg" id="nxt" alt="Next"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>  

        <div id="img-grp-wrap">
            <div class="img-wrap">
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image2.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image3.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">cccccccccccccccc
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image4.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">dddddddddddddddd
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image5.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image6.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">fffffffffffffffff
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideZ">
                <img src="images/slide_image7.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="captionZ">gggggggggggggggggg
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
```

*JS:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.img-wrap .slideZ:gt(0)').hide();
$('.nextbox').click(function() {
    $('.captionZ').fadeIn();
    $('.img-wrap .slideZ:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
});
$('.prevbox').click(function() {
    $('.captionZ').fadeIn();
    $('.img-wrap .slideZ:first-child').fadeOut();
    $('.img-wrap .slideZ:last-child').prependTo('.img-wrap').fadeOut();
    $('.img-wrap .slideZ:first-child').fadeIn();
 });
});
```

Comment: Works fine in IE11 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mfryrfyx/). Do you get any errors in the *console*?

Comment: Well it doesn't work for me!

Comment: Did you check the link? Does the fiddle not work in your browser?

Comment: I did, and it does work... So it has to be a conflict of some sorts. Any alternate ways to include the fadeIn() fadeOut()